Backend sends access-control-allow-origin: 'https://localhost:4000' but there is error in dev console that it is set to *
In devtools I see that backend is sending header:
access-control-allow-origin: 'https://localhost:4000'
But I get error in dev console:
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at ‘https://exampleurl/api/user/whoIam’. (Reason: Credential is not supported if the CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ is ‘*’).

My fetch request:
await fetch("https://exampleurl/api/user/whoIam", {
    "credentials": "omit",
    "headers": {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:126.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/126.0",
        "Accept": "*/*",
        "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
        "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
        "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
        "Sec-Fetch-Site": "cross-site",
        "Priority": "u=4",
        "Pragma": "no-cache",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache"
    },
    "referrer": "https://localhost:4000/",
    "method": "OPTIONS",
    "mode": "cors"
});

Response headers for OPTIONS request (preflight):
HTTP/2 204 
date: Wed, 22 May 2024 15:49:38 GMT
strict-transport-security: max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains
access-control-allow-origin: https://localhost:4000
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-methods: GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS
access-control-allow-headers: DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range,X-Forwarded-Email
access-control-expose-headers: Content-Length,Content-Range,X-Forwarded-Email
access-control-max-age: 1728000
content-length: 0
X-Firefox-Spdy: h2

There are no response headers for GET request.

Show the response.

@jub0bs Added response headers

What about the response to the actual request (as opposed to the preflight request)?

@jub0bs There are no response headers for GET request.

Ok. Please post the exact error message (as text, not as a picture).

I don't know what to tell you... Such a response could not have possibly triggered such an error. There must be something you're not telling us.

@jub0bs it is creazy, I know. I just replace domain with exampleurl and x-forwarded-email, that's it.

Hold on. The error message mentions https://exampleurl/api/user/whoIam whereas your fetch call is to https://exampleurl/api/table/lockedData. How do you reconcile that?

@jub0bs both requests fail with the same error. I have edited question to use only whoIam.
